# React Native + Gradle fails with Problems reading data from Binary store error (.gradle/.tmp/gradle7278112572988587194.bin offset 230266 exists? true)

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I was able to build my react native code successfully until yesterday but when I tried today I am getting gradle error

```
 * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in usr/.gradle/.tmp/gradle7278112572988587194.bin offset 230266 exists? true
```

I haven't changed anything in my code neither I have updated any dependencies.
Have tried all the possible solutions online including:

- cleaning the project and running it again
- updating the gradle
- deleting all temp and cache

Nothing worked for me. I am not even able to build the app for debugging.

ENV:

React: v18.1.0
react-native: v0.68.1
NativeBase: v3.4.3
react-native-firebase: v14.9.0

I am also not able to understand anything from the stacktrace

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /Users/himanshu/.gradle/.tmp/gradle13795124256216637934.bin offset 227972 exists? true

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:71)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:161)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:186)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:150)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:146)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:160)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:147)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:39)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareTaskExecution$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$1(StateTransitionController.java:222)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:221)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:190)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareTaskExecution(VintageBuildModelController.java:101)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.doBuildStages(VintageBuildModelController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$2(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:113)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.lambda$prepareTaskGraph$0(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:110)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withState(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:236)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.prepareTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:86)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$0(StateTransitionController.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:114)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:105)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolutionResult.getAllDependencies(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies$LenientResolutionResult.getAllDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1819)
        at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.afterResolve(DependencyInspector.java:176)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:149)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.afterResolve(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:657)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:635)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.lambda$resolveExclusively$4(DefaultConfiguration.java:615)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$CalculatedModelValueImpl.update(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:478)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:612)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:599)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphForBuildDependenciesIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:843)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$SelectedArtifactsProvider.getTaskDependencyValue(DefaultConfiguration.java:1338)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$SelectedArtifactsProvider.getTaskDependencyValue(DefaultConfiguration.java:1334)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1377)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FilteredFileCollection.visitDependencies(FilteredFileCollection.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)
        ... 136 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems reading data from Binary store in /Users/himanshu/.gradle/.tmp/gradle13795124256216637934.bin offset 227972 exists? true
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.DefaultBinaryStore$SimpleBinaryData.read(DefaultBinaryStore.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.StreamingResolutionResultBuilder$RootFactory.lambda$create$0(StreamingResolutionResultBuilder.java:189)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory$SimpleStore.load(CachedStoreFactory.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.StreamingResolutionResultBuilder$RootFactory.create(StreamingResolutionResultBuilder.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.StreamingResolutionResultBuilder$RootFactory.create(StreamingResolutionResultBuilder.java:159)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.getRoot(DefaultResolutionResult.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.allDependencies(DefaultResolutionResult.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultResolutionResult.getAllDependencies(DefaultResolutionResult.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolutionResult.getAllDependencies(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:224)
        ... 184 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (60) for constraint releaseCompileClasspath -> com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:{strictly 13.2.0}
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.DefaultResolutionResultBuilder.visitOutgoingEdges(DefaultResolutionResultBuilder.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.StreamingResolutionResultBuilder$RootFactory.deserialize(StreamingResolutionResultBuilder.java:239)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.DefaultBinaryStore$SimpleBinaryData.read(DefaultBinaryStore.java:130)
        ... 192 more
```

> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> changes everytime I try to build my app.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change this line in build.gradle

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'

to this

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5'

```
OR
This implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

to this

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:6'
```